# The webcam doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, asus, webcam

Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.13.0-39-generic

Some time ago the built-in camera stopped working.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
I would be glad for any help.
I see the following messages in the logs when I check with cheese

````
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD'  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event9 13:73 fd 96 paused 0  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: always reports core events  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) event9  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) event9  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) event9  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device removed  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input27/event9"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ",,"  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) event9  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard  
Apr  8 17:47:35 aleks-ASUS /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1624]: (II) event9  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard```
````

Comment: Have you made any `udev` changes?  Can you be more precise about the last time the camera "worked", and what changes you've made since? It looks like the camera is being recognized as a "keyboard".

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes to the udev. Some updates may have been installed. I'm not sure about this.
The camera was working accurately about 1 month ago